# Could someone provide me the script to load child swfs (located on cd) by projector file (located on c drive)?

Tags: flash

I want to distribute an application.  I want to install flash exe on c drive. Flash exe loads child swfs located on a cd. The problem is how to write the path of child swfs.  Different systems will have different letters, that is, d, e, f, g etc. To represent their cd drive. Could someone provide me the script to load child swfs (located on cd) by projector file (located on c drive)??

Comment: http://theoatmeal.com/panel/minor_differences?f0=caps_off-jpg&f1=caps_on-jpg

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly you want to do, but you can write a horrible workaround for this. I don't recommend this, as this is really just to go around the problem. Maybe your question is completely different, but this is what can be understood from it.

So, given the problem, you have files on a cd and you want to reach them. Now, you don't know the drive letter, therefore you don't know how to load the file.

Now, if we give another condition to the problem, we can do a workaround. Let's say, that on the cd you can always find a certain file. If not, then create a file with a name, what will always be on your cd (if you have different versions).

Then, the task is to find the drive letter:

```
var abc:String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

var letter_to_check:String = abc.charAt(0);

checkNextLetter();

function checkNextLetter():void
{
    if(abc.length == 0) return;

    letter_to_check = abc.charAt(0);

    var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
    ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener("complete", ldrDone);
    ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener("ioError", ldrError);
    ldr.load(new URLRequest(letter_to_check + ":\\yourfile.txt"));
}

function ldrDone(evt:*):void
{
    trace(letter_to_check, "loaded");
    abc = abc.slice(1);
    checkNextLetter();
}

function ldrError(evt:*):void
{
    trace(letter_to_check, "not loaded");
    abc = abc.slice(1);
    checkNextLetter();
}
```

Now here yourfile.txt, needs to be in the root of your cd. If you run this program, you will see the traces, and you will see when it finds the file.

So anytime `ldrDone` runs, you found a drive with the file.

So, if you are ready to use this monster (don't do it), put it in the beginning of your program, before anything happens. Then you can store the drive letter and use it later, when you need to know where to load the files from.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're up for using a third party projector tool then I can help you. I wrote a blog post called [Avoiding Windows Drive Not Ready Errors](http://www.northcode.com/blog.php/2008/09/12/Avoiding-Windows-Drive-Not-Ready-Errors) that shows how to enumerate all the drives on a system and find their labels. The example requires SWF Studio (a product I wrote) but it solves you problem pretty easily.

All you have to do is give your CD a volume label (which you can control) and then look for that label when you're enumerating drives. There's an example in the blog post. So if you know the path to the file on CD you can just access it directly. If you want to leave it more open, SWF Studio has commands that will let you get a list of all files on the CD.

SWF Studio can also tell you whether the drive you've found is a hard drive, a floppy or removable media so you can prevent people from copying your CD to a hard drive with the same volume label as a primitive (very primitve) form of copy protection.

Just let me know if you want/need to see any more examples.

Another upside here is that SWF Studio will work with AS1, AS2 and AS3.